# Restlet Directory - default index.html file not being served

Tags: java, restlet

I have:

```
Directory webdir = new Directory(getContext(), "clap://class/webapp");
webdir.setDeeplyAccessible(true);
router.attach("",webdir);
```

This works when serving all files in the directory by name.

However, it should serve `index.html` when you visit "/" and it doesn't.  I've tried all combinations of path, extra routers etc etc and it's still not working.

When you visit "/" you get a 200 response and an application/octet-stream content type.  The response is otherwise empty.  The `getIndexName` on Directory assures me it's `index`

I've also tried `getMetadataService().addExtension("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML, true);` to help it to pick up the index.html file but to no avail and also set the accept header in the request to text/html.

ETA: it is the same (unsolved) problem that's described here: http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/Serving-static-files-using-Directory-and-CLAP-from-a-jar-td7578543.html

Can anyone help with this?  It's driving me nuts.

After a bit of fiddling I have this workaround in place now, but I'd rather not redirect if possible:

```
        Redirector redirector = new Redirector(getContext(), "/index.html", Redirector.MODE_CLIENT_PERMANENT);
        TemplateRoute route = router.attach("/",redirector);
        route.setMatchingMode(Template.MODE_EQUALS);
```

Comment: did you try with webdir.setIndexName("index.html"); ?

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is caused by the way the `ClapClientHelper` class identifies a target as a file or directory. The workaround solution is to replace the ClapClientHelper class with another nearly identical one called say `JarClapClientHelper`. Copy the source code from `ClapClientHelper` and change the following snippet in the `handleClassLoader` method.

```
  // The ClassLoader returns a directory listing in some cases.
  // As this listing is partial, it is of little value in the context
  // of the CLAP client, so we have to ignore them.
  if (url != null) {
    if (url.getProtocol().equals("file")) {
      File file = new File(url.getFile());
      modificationDate = new Date(file.lastModified());

      if (file.isDirectory()) {
        url = null;
      }
    //NEW CODE HERE
    } else if (url.getProtocol().equals("jar")) {
      try {
        JarURLConnection conn = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        modificationDate = new Date(conn.getJarEntry().getLastModifiedTime().toMillis());
        if (conn.getJarEntry().isDirectory()) {
          url = null;
        }

      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        getLogger().log(Level.WARNING,
                "Unable to open the representation's input stream",
                ioe);
        response.setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
      }
    }
  }
```

Now you need to load this helper instead of the default one.
(Thanks to @Thierry Boileau.)

There are two ways, one that does not require any code, and one that is programmatic.
The first one is to let the [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#register-service-providers) find your service:

1. add a file called META-INF/services/org.restlet.engine.ClientHelper to your solution.
2. this file should have a single line of text: the full name (including the package) of your helper class

The second one is to add the helper programmatically:

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().add(0, new JarClapClientHelper(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the WAR protocol:

```
Directory directory = new Directory(getContext(), "war:///");
directory.setIndexName("index.html");
router.attach("/", directory);
```

Pay attention to the triple slash to identify the war package root, otherwise you will get `NullPointerException`.

(In my case I have a Maven project and my index file is put on the root of the generated war package).